# How to get output from SQLCMD or OSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd, osql

Looked everywhere... to no avail.

I am trying to do a basic select using SQLCMD from the command line:

`sqlcmd -S myServer -d myDB -E`

So far so good.

`select * from myTable`

Nothing, just goes to the next line. Shouldn't it display a table with values ? Or at least "n row(s) returned" ?

I also tried the -o param: it creates an empty file.

Comment: Without the -Q or -q parameters, SQLCMD and OSQL launch a command-line editor.  You will then need to enter the lines of queries, and then a GO on the final line to execute the batch.

Comment: Down-voter: how about you make your action constructive and explain what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When you use the SQLCMD tool in interactive mode statements that you enter are sent to the server when you use the keyword GO.

> GO signals both the end of a batch and the execution of any cached
>   Transact-SQL statements. When specifying a value for count, the cached
>   statements will be executed count times, as a single batch.

See [Use the sqlcmd Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx) specifically the section titled *Running Transact-SQL Statements Interactively by Using sqlcmd*

So in your case:

`select * from myTable` <kbd>enter</kbd>

`GO`<kbd>enter</kbd>